# .NET 3.5 how can I decompress a ZIP file with DotNetZip to a specified location

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following that works great if .NET 4.5 is installed

```
public static void SearchZippedLogs()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Searching compressed logs");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");

        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(sPath + "\\" + sDate + "\\");
        FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.zip");

        try
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(sPath + "\\" + sDate + "\\" + file.Name))
                {
                    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                    {
                        if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(".ininlog", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(temp);
                                entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(temp, entry.FullName));
                                try
                                {
                                    Stream sTemp = new FileStream(temp + "\\" + entry.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

                                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(sTemp))
                                    {
                                        string line;
                                        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                                        {
                                            if (line.Contains(sTerm))
                                            {
                                                Console.WriteLine("{0} contains\"{1}\"", file.Name, sTerm);
                                                if (bLog)
                                                    Logger(file.Name + " contains " + sTerm, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME") + "-" + sTerm);
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ae)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(ae.Message);
                                    if (bLog)
                                        Logger(ae.Message, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME") + "-" + sTerm);
                                }
                                catch (SystemException se)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(se.Message);
                                    if (bLog)
                                        Logger(se.Message, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME") + "-" + sTerm);
                                }
                                catch (ApplicationException ape)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(ape.Message);
                                    if (bLog)
                                        Logger(ape.Message, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME") + "-" + sTerm);
                                }
                                catch (Exception e)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                                    if (bLog)
                                        Logger(e.Message, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME") + "-" + sTerm);
                                }
                            }
                            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ae)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(ae.Message);
                                if (bLog)
                                    Logger(ae.Message, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME") + "-" + sTerm);
                            }
                            catch (SystemException se)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(se.Message);
                                if (bLog)
                                    Logger(se.Message, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME") + "-" + sTerm);
                            }
                            catch (ApplicationException ape)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(ape.Message);
                                if (bLog)
                                    Logger(ape.Message, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME") + "-" + sTerm);
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                                if (bLog)
                                    Logger(e.Message, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME") + "-" + sTerm);
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                Directory.Delete(temp, true);
                                archive.Dispose();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The problem is on our servers are only running .NET 3.5 due to software we run, I need to accomplish the same thing using .NET 3.5

I have looked at DotNetZip and DeflateStream Class but am having troubles replicating this to .NET 3.5

Expected outcome Extract each zip file in the directory to a temporary location, search through it for a item, if found print the filename then delete the temporary items

Thanks for the assistance

So I think I worked it out using the following

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Ionic.Zip;
namespace DotNetTest
{
  class Program
  {
    private static string sPath;
    private static string sTempLoc = Path.GetTempPath() + Path.GetRandomFileName();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Path");
        sPath = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Looking in " + sPath);

        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(sPath + "\\");
        FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.zip");

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);
            using (ZipFile archive = ZipFile.Read(file.FullName))
            {
                foreach(ZipEntry e in archive)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Extracting " + e.FileName + " to " + sTempLoc);
                    e.Extract(sTempLoc, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Finsihed! Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I think DotNetZip is the best solution in this case. So your question should be: how can I decompress a ZIP file with DotNetZip to a specified location? The DotNetZip site has many examples showing you exactly how to do this, so I don't see how you could be having any trouble at all. Maybe you can elaborate?

Comment: John give me a few and I will try and elaborate

Comment: Why repeat that here? The project has an [examples page](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CS-Examples&referringTitle=Examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method that'll do that.  Just pass the file's path and the destination directory as arguments.

```
private void UnZip(string filePath, string targetPath)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath) || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(targetPath))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Arguments cannot be null or empty.");
    }

    using (ZipFile zf = ZipFile.Read(filePath))
    {
        foreach (var entry in zf)
        {
            entry.Extract(targetPath, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
        }
    }
}
```